# Unity and resolving many small objects

Tags: unity-container

I am using Unity in a desktop WPF application. I have a ListView with many items and I am using unitycontainer to resolve the instances of each ViewModel for every ListViewItem. I realized that those ViewModels resolved with the container will never be garbage collected and that is a memory leak. What is the practice in this case? Should I manually construct those lists of viewmodels or Unity provide solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the life cycle of the objects created, you can simply register them with the `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager`. This will tell Unity that once it creates an object, it's not in charge of keeping the object alive or anything, so the GC will eventually collect it down the road, once no references are kept to the objects.

[That documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx) is no longer updated, but the information regarding that LifetimeManager is still relevant.

Note: I'm not sure I'd have unity instantiate a ton of tiny objects, but with so little information, I can't really offer advice beyond that answer.